# ELASTICSEARCH - Filter_path on multiples fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Is it possible to make a filter_path on several fields?
I try to do this:

```
GET company/_search?filter_path=hits.hits._search&filter_path=hits.hits._search._sort
```

But only return the field "hits.hits._search._sort"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what `hits.hits._search` is but you can surely include several fields using filter_path:

```
GET company/_search?filter_path=hits.hits.sort,hits.hits._source.title,hits.hits._id
```